# How can I set Jenkins configuration from config-file-provider plugin in every job (per default)

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In our company, we have a project using a very old jenkins installation (1.658) with a very old version of the config-file-provider plugin. I am currently migrating this to a new jenkins instance, using jenkins 2.203 and config-file-provider 3.6.2 version.

It works well, but one of my users is complaining, that he must select the jenkins settings.xml and global config in every single jenkins project under "Build -> Advanced -> settings file / global settings file".

With the old versions, he was able to select this once under "Configure jenkins -> configure system -> Maven Configuration" globally for the wohle jenkins instance and the selection was then added to every new project by default. But this seems to be disappeared in the new versions of jenkins and/or the plugin.

Can someone tell me, if I am doing something wrong or if the possibility to select the maven settings globally for all projects is really gone (and if it is really gone, why one would disable this feature)?

Comment: Settings the settings.xml in each jobs sounds like an issue in the build ...or better within the maven configuration/pom file...The settings.xml should only contain configuration for the repositories to be consumes which is usually a repository manager plus credentials which can handled with the credentials plugin...

Comment: @khmarbaise I do not understand you comment. In every project under "Build -> Advanced -> settings file / global settings file" I select settings file = provided settings.xml and then the file saved with config-file-provider plugin. And in my old jenkins, I could do this once in jenkins system configuration and it was then selected for all projects per default. Maybe the word "job" was unclear, I will change it to "project".

Comment: To be honest I used the manual configuration for a job a long long time ago ..only using via pipeline scripts...So I'm not sure if this can be done or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. It has been moved to "Manage Jenkins -> Configure Tools". Just in case anyone needs this info sometimes.

Comment: You cannot use it for old projects, though.
See https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-21323